# SSH stopped forwarding ports

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, port-forwarding

Somehow SSH stopped forwarding ports and giving me errors on the host. I can not figure out why. I tried -4 switch to force ip4 but still no luck.I am hoping that I could get much proper solution here.

I restarted both the host and the client multiple times without any luck. I am guessing that this has to be a client issue because I get the same problem when I ssh (with same forwards) to a Windows ssh (Cygwin) server.

Here is some errors from the host

```
    debug1: Local connections to localhost:8123 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:8123
    debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8123.
    bind: Cannot assign requested address
    channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8123
    debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8111 forwarded to remote address socks:0
    debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8111.
    bind: Cannot assign requested address
    channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8111
    Could not request local forwarding.
```

Both are on Debian64.

Comment: Run `sudo netstat -ntlp` on your ssh client.  Are you sure you don't have something else already listening on those ports?  Do you have an SSH connection that didn't get closed properly perhaps?

Comment: netstat shows it is all clean. I also restarted these pcs multiple times since then. Plus this all was working perfectly fine for like 6 months. The only issue I can tell you is that my laptop shutdown due to battery drain (there was ssh connection open then) But I restarted to laptop so I would think it should all be resetted fine?

Comment: What distro are you running?  Could this be an selinux issue perhaps?

Comment: @Zoredache, Both are Debian 64. It cant be selinux because I have been using this for a while without any issue unless some stuff about selinux changed this morning via updates.

Comment: It is possible to use selinux on Debian.  Though it certainly isn't standard.  I was just wildly speculating.  What you probably need to do is start by your ssh server, in debug mode with a high level of verbosity, then connect with your client with a high level of verbosity.  You might get more useful errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that the loopback network device was disabled. Enabling it solved this issue